# Servlet doesnt write JSON Output to AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, servlets

Following code for my output:

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     


    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ToJson obj = new ToJson();
    String obj1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    out.print(obj1);

    System.out.println(obj1);

    out.close();
```

The obj1 looks like this: `{"prname1":"P1neu","anz1":"342356","prid1":"1","price1":"25"}`

It should send the string out so I can parse it in my AJAX and display it but somwhow it ends up with nothing as console.log/etc doesnt display any data.

I had `out.append` but it also didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to send response as JSON.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(obj1);
```

Please check this [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax/4113258)

It will surely help you.